# dsearchn equivalent in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, numpy, scipy

Is there a Scipy or Numpy function that does the job of `dsearchn` MATLAB command in python?

`dsearchn` returns the index of nearest value to the input value in the given vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method of approximately equivalent efficiency is probably scipy's [`KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) or better yet [`cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html):

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

kdt = KDTree(P.T)
kdt.query(PQ.T)
```

Here `P` and `PQ` are the points and query points from the [`dsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html) docs. MATLAB uses the first dimension as the dimensionality of the points, while scipy uses the last, hence the transpose.

Unlike the MATLAB approach, which is done in a single step, using a `KDTree` us done in two steps: first you construct the tree object, then you run a [`query`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query) on it.

Comment: Is its syntax like MATLAB's `dsearchn`? Because it doesn't give index of value with lowest distance in euclidean space. I looked at the docs too but I didn't get how it works and why you transposed the `PQ`? the `PQ` can be a scalar and it doesn't need transposing.

Comment: @Enigmacy. According to the docs the scipy and Matlab versions interpret the dimensions backwards relative to each other. You don't need to transpose if your array is already in the right format. The return value of `query` contains both a value and an index. Which docs did you read?

Comment: I checked this [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) from Scipy v1.6.1

Comment: That's a good start. Take a look at the query method as well. I've added a link and a blurb to the answer: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
x = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.22, 1.4])
v  = 1.21

def dsearchnn(x, v):
    return np.where(np.abs(x-v) == np.abs(x-v).min())[0]
dsearchnn(x, v)
array([1,2])
```

Comment: Is there anyway to detect two indices with same distances? for example in x = [1.1, 1.2, 1.22, 1.3, 1.4], values 1.2 and 1.22 have same distance from `v`.

Comment: Yes, just edited the answer. There might be a problem with floating-point precision. @Enigmacy

Comment: `dsearchn` is intended for multidimensional points, not just scalars

Answer (score 0):

for x and v are both vectors:

```py
def dsearchn(x, v):
    z=np.atleast_2d(x)-np.atleast_2d(v).T
    return np.where(np.abs(z).T==np.abs(z).min(axis=1))[0]
```